# I want to write a python code in Ruby script, how can that be done?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, python-3.8

I have the following code in Python script 1.py that executes read_config.rb ruby script when run.

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_rb, muterun_rb
success = execute_rb('read_config.rb')
```

Now here is a read_config.rb Ruby file

```
from my-vpc-netapp-only import Variables      # Python line of code to be executed 
require 'erb'
require 'yaml'

region= 'ap-south-1'
k8sver='1.18'
vpccidr= '192.168.0.0/16'
vpcid = Variables.VPC_ID
pubsubnet1a = Variables.PUBSUBNET1A
pubsubnet1b = Variables.PUBSUBNET1B
prisubnet1a = Variables.PRISUBNET1A
prisubnet1b = Variables.PRISUBNET1B

template = ERB.new File.read 'managedcluster.yaml.erb'

File.open('managedcluster.yaml', 'w') do |f|
  f.write template.result(binding)
end
```

In this Ruby file, I am importing class Variables from another python script.
What changes could be made so that scripts get executed without any error?

Comment: see http://www.decalage.info/python/ruby_bridge for an overview of your options, personally I would read the variables from you netapp in Ruby itself, no need for Python

Comment: Why not just pass the variables to the ruby script? `from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_rb, muterun_rb; from my-vpc-netapp-only import Variables; success = execute_rb('read_config.rb', [YOUR VARIABLES HERE])` then in the ruby script you can read them from `ARGV`. [Basic article on ARGV](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/ruby-command-line-argv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, `my-vpc-netapp-only` is a running app, and thats why you need to automate fetching variable values using an import equivalent. Otherwise you could handpick some variables from `my-vpc-netapp-only.py`. in that assumption, it is a matter of writing

```
PUBSUBNET1A
PUBSUBNET1B
PRISUBNET1A
PRISUBNET1B
```

to a file whenever it changes while running `my-vpc-netapp-only.py` and you read it in ruby script to make the yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

> In this ruby file i am importing class Variables from another python script. What changes could be made to so that scripts get executed without any error ?

The line is not syntactically valid Ruby, so the first thing you would need to do is to modify it such that it becomes valid Ruby. Maybe something like this:

```ruby
import(:Variables, from: :'my-vpc-netapp-only')
```

Step #2 is to write a Python interpreter in Ruby which provides an `import` method that can import Python modules as Ruby objects.